# How to count the occurrences of a specific value in a single column in R

Tags: r, count

I have a df such as

```
a     b     sex
yes  yes    male
no   yes    female
yes  no     male
```

I would like to count and store as an object only the count of males in the sex column.

I am running this:

```
n_male <- length(grep('male', tbl1_df[ ,"sex"]))
n_male
```

Because 'male' is in 'female', however, I am getting `n_male = 3`. How can I change this function to make it `n_male = 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example showed, there is no need for substring matching.  We can directly use fixed match with `==` and get the count with `sum` of logical vector

```
n_male <- sum(tbl1_df$sex == 'male')
n_male
#[1] 2
```

---

With `grep`, it can also match substring.  There is `male` in `fe`male.

If we want to use `grep`, specify a word boundary

```
n_male <- sum(grepl('\\bmale\\b', tbl1_df$sex))
```

Or with `length/grep`

```
n_male <- length(grep('\\bmale\\b', tbl1_df$sex))
```

---

Also, in `base R`, we can just use `table`

```
table(tbl1_df$sex)
```

to get the counts of both

Answer (score 1):

If you could use the `mosaic` package, then you could do:

```
library(mosaic)
tally(~sex, data = tbl1_df)

sex
female   male 
     1      2
```

Answer (score 1):

`count()` lets you quickly count the unique values of one or more variables: `df %>% count(a, b)`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(sex)
```